# Idiomatic way to pattern match a Mutex-wrapped trait implementer enum?

Tags: rust

I'm using the [enum_dispatch](https://crates.io/crates/enum_dispatch) crate and want to wrap some of my `MyBehaviorEnum`s in a `Mutex`, then insert them into a `HashMap`. Without the Mutex, when I get items from the HashMap, I can easily pattern match for different `MyBehaviorEnum` values. But I'm not exactly sure how to do this kind of matching when the `MyHeaviorEnum` values are wrapped in a Mutex, or what an idiomatic approach might look like.

```
enum_dispatch = "0.3.7"
```

```rust
use core::convert::TryInto;
use enum_dispatch::enum_dispatch;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::collections::HashMap; 
struct MyImplementorA {}

impl MyBehavior for MyImplementorA {
    fn my_trait_method(&self) {}
}

struct MyImplementorB {}

impl MyBehavior for MyImplementorB {
    fn my_trait_method(&self) {}
}

#[enum_dispatch]
enum MyBehaviorEnum {
    MyImplementorA,
    MyImplementorB,
}

#[enum_dispatch(MyBehaviorEnum)]
trait MyBehavior {
    fn my_trait_method(&self);
}

fn main() {
    //No Mutex wrapper
    let a: MyBehaviorEnum = MyImplementorA {}.into();
    let a2: MyBehaviorEnum = MyImplementorA {}.into();
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert("First", a);
    map.insert("Second", a2);

    match map.get_mut("First"){
        Some(MyBehaviorEnum::MyImplementorA(a_instance)) =>{
            a_instance.my_trait_method();
        }
        _=>()
    }

    //Implementor enum values are wrapped in Mutex then inserted into HashMap
    let a: MyBehaviorEnum = MyImplementorA {}.into();
    let a2: MyBehaviorEnum = MyImplementorA {}.into();
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert("First", Mutex::new(a));
    map.insert("Second", Mutex::new(a2));

    match map.get_mut("First"){
        Some(mutex_impl_a)=>{
            match Mutex::into_inner(mutex_impl_a){
                Ok(MyBehaviorEnum::MyImplementorA(a_instance)) =>{
                     a_instance.my_trait_method();
                }
                _=>()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Comment: `match &*mutex.lock().unwrap()`

Comment: My question also relates to the ergonomics of using a Mutex in this manner. It's a lot of nested match statements. This all relates to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68264551/keep-global-hashmap-values-in-sync-with-struct-hashmap-values, by the way.

Comment: Also how do you get the error message by running the compiler directly?

Comment: via `cargo build`

Comment: But don't run cargo build and paste the error from vscode? It gives me the same error report.  Should I run ```cargo build``` some where else?

Comment: If you type in `cargo build` and see output that is multiple lines per error, that’s the ticket. I mostly mean not to copy from the IDEs error/warning window which hides most of the details.

Comment: Also in this case I would like a mutable reference to the contents of the ```mutex.lock().unwrap()```, but I don't believe ```&mut* mutex``` is a thing. So just ```*mutex```.

Comment: What happens where you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with the mutex wrapped values, use:

```rust
    match map.get_mut("First"){
        Some(mutex_impl_a)=>{
            match &*mutex_impl_a.lock().unwrap(){
                MyBehaviorEnum::MyImplementorA(a_instance)=>{
                    dbg!("got it!");
                }
                _=>()
            }
        }
        _=>()
    }
```